# How do I solve a differential equation on this form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a differential equation I am a bit confused about. Basically, I want to express $x_1(t)$ in terms of $x_2(t)$.

This is how they are related (I will let $\dot{x} = \frac{d}{dt} x$):

\begin{equation}
\dot{x_2}(t)^2 = -\dot{x_1}(t)^2 e^{2c x_2(t)}
\end{equation}
where c is a constant.

so basically I have two differential equations that are equal to each other. I don't know how to solve this at all.

Could I rewrite it as $$\dot{x_1} = - \dot{x_2} e^{-c x_2}$$
And just solve for $x_2(t)$ treating the L.H.S as a constant? I am not sure that is allowed.

Comment: $\dot{x}_1$ is not constant.  What you could do is to integrate both sides with respect to $t$.

Comment: Are these functions complex-valued or real-valued? In the latter case, we have $\dot{x}_1 = 0 = \dot{x}_2$ just by looking at the signs of both sides.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dot{x_2}(t)^2 = -\dot{x_1}(t)^2 e^{2c x_2(t)}$$
$$(\dot{x_2}(t)^2 -i^2\dot{x_1}(t)^2 e^{2c x_2(t)})=0$$
$$(\dot{x_2}(t) -i\dot{x_1}(t) e^{c x_2(t)})(\dot{x_2}(t) +i\dot{x_1}(t) e^{c x_2(t)})=0$$
Then you have the equations:
$$(\dot{x_2}(t) -i\dot{x_1}(t) e^{c x_2(t)})=0$$
$$(\dot{x_2}(t) +i\dot{x_1}(t) e^{c x_2(t)})=0$$
Then you can integrate both equations.
$$\int e^{-c x_2}dx_2=\pm i\int  dx_1$$

Answer (score 1):

If we look at

\begin{equation}
\dot{x_2}(t)^2 = -\dot{x_1}(t)^2 e^{2c x_2(t)},
\end{equation}

then we have $\dot{x_2}(t)^2 \ge 0$ and $e^{2c x_2(t)}>0.$

Hence $-\dot{x_1}(t)^2  \ge 0$, thus $\dot{x_1}(t)^2 \le 0$, which gives $\dot{x_1}(t)=0,$

Then

\begin{equation}
\dot{x_2}(t)^2 = -\dot{x_1}(t)^2 e^{2c x_2(t)},
\end{equation}
becomes

$$\dot{x_2}(t)=0$$

Consequence: each pair of constant function satiesfies the differential equation.